# Migrations in EF 5 failing after upgrading from EF 4.3

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-4.0, entity-framework-5

I am just trying to upgrade from EF 4.3 to EF 5 while on .Net 4.0

When I run the migrations using `update-database` I get this:

```
System.Data.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Namespace'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Provider'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'ProviderManifestToken'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Alias'.
(0,0) : error 0010: The element Schema in namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl was unexpected for the root element. The expected Schema in one of the following namespaces: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm/ssdl, http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl.
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.ThrowOnNonWarningErrors()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.XDocumentExtensions.GetStoreItemCollection(XDocument model, DbProviderInfo& providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, String connectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.IsModelOutOfDate(XDocument model, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Namespace'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Provider'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'ProviderManifestToken'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Alias'.
(0,0) : error 0010: The element Schema in namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl was unexpected for the root element. The expected Schema in one of the following namespaces: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm/ssdl, http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl.
```

Any way to get pass this while being on .Net 4.0? I know some features of EF 5 aren't available on .Net 4. But I can't upgrade to .Net 4.5 or VS 2012 because my SSD is only of 60GB and currently it has just 4 GBs free and so the VS2012 installer won't let me install that (even on other drive).

Web.config has reference to this one:

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

Comment: What does the web.config for that project look like?

Comment: The issue here is that the model being loaded is in v3 schema while the EF components in .NET Framework 4 understand only v2 schema. How did you install EF5? What is the version of EntityFramework.dll you are using (I asume it is 5.0.0.0 while the version of EF5 EntityFramework.dll on .NET Framework 4 should be 4.4.0.0)

Comment: @Pawel: You are right it is 4.4. I updated the post. I installed it through nuget. Further it throws the error the 1st time I load then if I refresh the page,  it works fine. But then when I again refresh the page the app hangs forever and I have to do a iisreset and after that the cycle again repeats :). Very annoying!

Comment: Have you ever migrated your database with migrations from EF5 on .NET Framework 4.5?

Comment: @Pawel: No. Actually, I have one more developer with me and he migrated his DB to EF 5 with .Net 4.5. But when I am trying to do it on .Net 4 and it throws error (and works sometimes).

Comment: I was never able to make it run. I finally uninstalled VS2010 and installed VS2012 and .Net 4.5.

Comment: I think the reason for the error was that when the other developer used EF5 on .NET Framework 4.5 it updated the model in the database to use v3 schema version which .NET Framework 4 cannot handle. I can't explain why it sometimes worked... Hopefully installing .NET 4.5 and EF5 for .NET Framework 4.5 solved the problem.

Comment: @Pawel: But he has his own local database. I have my own local database. Anyways, yes it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the model stored in the database has v3 schema while you are using .NET Framework 4 to update-database. EF components in .NET Framework 4 does not understand v3 (only v2) schemas and hence the error. I beleive you need to move to .NET Framework 4.5 and VS2012.